# Python 3. Gtk 3. Wnck. Как не показывать определённые окна/программы?

Tags: python, gtk

Как с помощью `wnck` не показывать определённые окна приложений? К примеру, я получаю список всех открытых приложений:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck

Gtk.main_iteration()

screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
screen.force_update()
screen.get_windows()
```

Вывод:

```
  Window object at 0x167bd20 (WnckWindow at 0x195d0e0),
  Window object at 0x167bf00 (WnckWindow at 0x195d740),
  Window object at 0x167bf50 (WnckWindow at 0x195d850)
```

К примеру, моё приложение называтся "SampleApp". Как получить его индификатор и скрыть его из списка?

Answer (score 1):

Метод get_windows() возвращает список объектов типа Wnck.Window ([https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Screen.html#Wnck.Screen.get_windows)](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Screen.html#Wnck.Screen.get_windows). У таких объектов есть метод get_name() - https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Window.html#Wnck.Window.get_name. Все сложив получится:

```
restricted_names = {"SampleApp", "SecondApp"}
windows = [wind for wind in screen.get_windows() if wind.get_name() not in restricted_names]
```